# How can I download a game on to my account and not have it download to other accounts on the Xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one

How can I download a game onto my account t and not have it download to other accounts on the Xbox One?

Comment: The games are downloaded to the Xbox One, not the accounts. Are you trying to prevent other accounts from accessing those games?

Comment: Are you trying to hide that the game is downloaded, or simply prevent other accounts from accessing it?

Comment: Prevent other accounts from using them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot decide who can or cannot access the game, it is installed for all users. What will change is the access to the xbox live, which will only be accessible if the user who launches the game has a subscription. Game data also differs from one account to another (for example, when you start story mode in "game 1", the second user cannot retrieve the progress in the game.)